# Branching in Git and recover to another branch

Tags: git, github, gitlab

Ok, I have a git with the master branch and a altered (twig) branch.

Right now they are in this way:

```
    Master Update - o  o -> Altered Twig Branch
                    |  |
                    | /
                    |/
  Master Original - o
```

Right now, when I change the master, I need to manually incorporate the alterations on the altered twig. But the twig is heavily altered form from the master.

There is a ease way to do this?
Or I need to incorporate manually?

Comment: Do you want to merge the changes from `Altered Twig Branch` into `master`? `git merge` can do that.

Comment: If you only need to apply certain commits from master to the altered branch you can use `git cherrypick <commithash>` (executed when on the altered branch).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, to be comfortable and safe, do a quick backup for your master branch.

```
git branch backup_master master
```

Then, as kowsky commented, the general principle is to merge `altered_twig` into `master` :

```
git checkout master
git merge altered_twig
```

Note : at this point, it is possible (depending on the nature of your changes) that conflicts arise on some files. It is *not* an error. It's git's way to prompt you for the arbitrary choices it can't do automatically. The point is already documented in the [manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#_how_to_resolve_conflicts), but there are also a lot of good answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-to-resolve-merge-conflicts-in-git) or [elsewhere](http://weblog.masukomi.org/2008/07/12/handling-and-avoiding-conflicts-in-git/) on the web on this subject. (and you can abort the process with `git merge --abort`)

If the end result isn't what you expect or you want to recover the inital state of `master` for any reason, just switch back to your `master` branch :

```
git branch -f master backup_master
```